# Android Picture Viewer

Tags: android, gallery, imageview

I have an app that at the moment is just a gallery of pictures, with an ImageView below which shows the picture that the user has clicked on.

At the moment I have hacked together this code:

```
gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

     ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

     public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id)
     {              
          switch (position){
          case 0 : iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.sample_1);break;
          case 1 : iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.sample_2);break;
          case 2 : iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.sample_3);break;
          case 3 : iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.sample_4);break;
          case 4 : iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.sample_5);break;
          case 5 : iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.sample_6);break;
          }
     }
});
```

However, if I had thousands of photos I wouldn't want to have a massive switch statement, rather something where "sample_"

How can I rewrite this function to be faster with less lines of code.

I think I need to access the id of each of my drawables..is that possible?

Many thanks

Ed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can proceed as follows:

```
gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id)  {           
        final String fileName = "drawablename_" + position;
        final int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(fileName, "drawable", "your.package.name");

        iv.setImageResource(resId);   
    }
});
```

This way this is just a matter of drawable naming convention: you call your drawables "drawablename_1", "drawablename_2", etc... and `getIdentifier()` retrieves their `R` ids for you.

Comment: Be mindful that this sort of "lookup by name" is slow, but it may still be your best option if loading resources from the drawable folder.

Comment: @jrobinson3k1 Yes, that's true (+1). It's only when you cannot determine your R identifier any other way than dynamically. - Edd, you are welcome!

Comment: It does say using getIdentifier is discouraged because it is so slow, although for this purpose I feel it will do just fine.

Surely this is faster than using a 1000(0)+ entry switch statement anyway?

Comment: Here, this will be calculated for only one image per user click, and a user clisk is really slow compared to the machine's performances. So this is OK. But filling a complete array for all the images in a row using this method would probably take time, yes. And using a big switch() with all the R.id would be way faster, but I definitely don't suggest going that way. Give a try first and see whether it actually needs optimization (I don't think it does in this specific use case).

Comment: @Shlublu - A big switch statement is probably about as fast as your implementation actually, as it has to check each case until it finds a match, which is probably also the case with `getIdentifier()`

Comment: @jrobinson3k1 Here, I build an String to call getResources() that has to retrieve a file name in a given folder and then to give me back a corresponding integer. A series of as integer comparisons, even numerous, is certainly faster. But well, a big switch has no many drawbacks (maintenance, etc) that this is not so much the question here.

Answer (score 1):

I would move your images you will be using to your Assets folder. You can load files from your asset folder as if they were just a plain ole directory, including pictures. Then when you need to show a picture, your OnClickListener would look like this:

```
gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

     ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

     public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id)
     {              
          String fileName = "sample_" + (position + 1);
          InputStream in = getAssets().open(fileName);
          Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
          iv.setImageBitmap(bm);
     }
});
```

Note that loading the picture is an O(1) operation.

Comment: Yes, that's a good idea. This is the way I would do too I think.

Comment: Please explain why I would use this method as opposed to the one above, Thanks

Comment: As I said at the end of my response, this is an O(1) operation, whereas the "lookup by name" method is most likely O(n). If you're unfamiliar with O-notation, then to put it simply, it's faster :)

Comment: I'll explain a little better. The "lookup by name" method has to potentially check every drawable in your folder before it finds the one you want because you're using a String reference to locate the file. Well, files in your resource directories are referenced by identifiers, not their actually names. So when you attempt to load by name, it has to check all your drawables until it finds a match, then give you the identifier associated with it so you can load it. This method will go directly to the file where the image is stored and load it.

Comment: I would add that this is also a question of design: if we don't intend to access the resources by their R identifiers but as files, it's better to use the Asset folder which is here for that purpose. And its true it is also faster as no "scan" is needed. I don't know how getIdentifier() works internally, but it has to do things to retrieve the resources by their name and that are not needed here.

Comment: Ultimately, you may or may not notice a visual difference between the two different methods...as your drawable folder grows, the longer the operation will take. It also depends on the phone's hardware (processor), but that's probably a little too technical for a problem of this magnitude.

Answer (score 0):

Keep an array of the IDs that is in the same order as the views in the gallery

```
int[] picIDs = new int[10];
picIDs[0] = R.drawable.sample_1;
picIDs[1] = R.drawable.sample_2;
picIDs[2] = R.drawable.sample_3;
etc...
```

Then in your click listener do something like this:

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id)
 {              
      iv.setImageResource(picIDs[position]);
 }
```

Comment: Still requires a large block of code if I had thousands of photos... and requires the extra memory indexing them.

Answer (score -1):

An easier way to create your int[] picIds array is:

```
  int[] picIds=new int[]{R.drawable.sample_1,R.drawable.sample_2,R.drawable.sample_3};
```